# Как подцепить MinGW64 к code::blocks?

Tags: компиляция, codeblocks

Забыл, как подцепить MinGW64 к code::blocks.

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
 int *p;
 std::cout<<sizeof(p)<<std::endl;
 return 0;
}
```

выводит 4, а должно выводить 8. Каталог minhw64 в C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks скопирован, разрядность системы 64 бита. А что надо в самой среде прописать и куда?

Comment: Вы хотите указать компилятор? Settings -> Global Compiler Settings -> Toolchain executables

Comment: Да, именно это я и хотел. Напишите, как ответ, приму.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Указать компилятор в Code::Blocks можно через настройки:

*Settings -> Global Compiler Settings -> Toolchain executables*